# Loop for youtube-dl to download one of either formats (depending on errors)

Tags: bash, loops, error-handling, youtube-dl

Trying to download 100+ videos, most of which are available in "-f 43 format" I do sometimes get an error "ERROR: requested format not available".

So I'd like to have a loop that in those cases tries the same download, but in "-f 18" format (which is similar enough).

I think this should be possible, probably in bash, but I have no clear idea how. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Thanks, I understand my question is 'bland' (or perhaps even appears lazy) but I haven't tried much more since 1) I didn't know where to start, and 2) I hoped there was some other solution (like the one below). I do genuinely appreciate your tip though, I will keep it in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for external coding; youtube-dl includes this functionality natively. Simply add slashes in your `-f` parameter. For instance, if you want format 43, failing that 18, and failing that simply the best available single file, call youtube-dl like this:

```
youtube-dl -f 43/18/best https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc
```

For more information, refer to the [official documentation on format selection](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#format-selection).